# How to get value ForRowAt indexPath in tableview?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a problem to co-relate and get desired output from the following two arrays:

**Scenario:**

1. I have 2 Arrays as follows:

**sectionArray**

```
[["mbsdcie6_2_1": Incomer 132 KV Parameters, "mbsdcie6_2_2": <__NSCFArray 0x604000115180>(
3,
6,
4,
5,
8,
30,
31,
7,
18,
29,
1
)
], ["mbsdcie6_2_1": SMS2 Parameters, "mbsdcie6_2_2": <__NSCFArray 0x6040000a3f60>(
9,
10,
11,
12,
13,
14
)
], ["mbsdcie6_2_1": SMS 1 Parameters, "mbsdcie6_2_2": <__NSCFArray 0x604000267880>(
15,
17
)
]]
```

**ParamName**

```
["Date", "Sync Time", "UUC2T7", "Set MD", "Total KVA", "Total KW", "Running MD", "SMS 1 KW", "P.F.", "ET-5 KW", "ET-3_4 KW", "ET- 6_7 KW", "ABP-1 KW", "ABP-1A KW", "ABP-2 KW", "G-22 KW", "UUC36T37", "G-23 KW", "WRM KW", "Total KWH", "Total KVAH", "ET-5 KWH", "ET-3_4 KWH", "ET-6_7 KWH", "ABP-1 KWH", "ABP-1A KWH", "ABP-2 KWH", "SMS 1 KWH", "UUC60T73", "PLC Time", "Voltage", "Current", "Load Factor", "Avg. P.F."]
```

**Problem:**

- Now I wish to get the value from **paramName** as per the indexes of the key **"mbsdcie6_2_2"** from **sectionArray** in my **tableView** method **cellForRowAt indexPath**

**For Example:**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
    {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DataMonitorCell", for: indexPath) as! DataMonitorCell

    cell.lblParameter.text = "Set MD" // value as per the index value 3 of key "mbsdcie6_2_2" from sectionArray

return cell
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

- **This is how I retrieve sectionArray:**

  var sectionArray = Dictionary

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          sectionArray = kUserDefault.array(forKey: kHeadersArray) as! [Dictionary]

  ```
      print(sectionArray)
  }
  ```
- **This is how I retrieve ParamName**

  // In my another ViewController, I am retrieving it like this:

  var paramName = String

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  ```
      paramName = kUserDefault.value(forKey: kParameterNameArray) as! [String]

      print(paramName)
  }
  ```

I have tried many ways but it seems complicated for me. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `let mbsdcie6_2_2 = array1[indexPath.section] as [Int]; let index = mbsdcie6_2_2[indexPath.row] cell.lblParameter.text = array2[index]`?

Comment: It seems I forgot a step: `let mbsdcie6_2_2 = array1[indexPath.section] as [Int]` => `let something = array1[indexPath.section] as [String: Any]; let mbsdcie6_2_2 = something["mbsdcie6_2_2"] as [Int]`